# Spatial Index in MySQL - ERROR - Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

Tags: mysql, geometry, geolocation, spatial-index, mysql-error-1416

I am new to the whole 'spatial index' thing, but it seems to be the best solution for filtering based on latitude/longitude. So I added a column to my table:

So I created a `geometry` field:

```
  ALTER TABLE `addresses` ADD `point` POINT NOT NULL
```

And then I tried to add an index:

```
  ALTER TABLE `addresses` ADD SPATIAL INDEX ( `point` )
```

But I get an error:

```
  #1416 - Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

OK I found the solution: Can't create a spatial index if some of the column fields contain no data. After running

```
  UPDATE `addresses` SET `point` = POINT( lng, lat )
```

Everything worked fine.

Comment: I now see that your answer is the same as mine, I tried to copy verbatim and it complained about lat and long being undefined :P ...

Comment: The order of POINT is lng, lat as POINT( lng, lat ), Please change your answer to avoid future mistakes.

Comment: @RamsésFernández **That is not true** according to [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/182626/140128) . MySQL handles it differently than PostGIS

Answer (score 5):

I had this same error (Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field)  but when trying to import spatial data from a mysql dump.
I found that some rows had "null"  (X is null or Y is null) spatial data even though the column was "NOT NULL"..

Check if you have the same problem as I'm describing with this SQL:

> SELECT id FROM locations WHERE X(coordinates) IS NULL OR Y(coordinates) IS NULL;

If you have some rows then this is what worked for me:

> UPDATE locations SET coordinates = POINT(0,0) WHERE X(coordinates) IS NULL OR Y(coordinates) IS NULL;

Then try your mysqldump (or from phpmyadmin) and import again.