# Inserting a point into MySQL 8.0 from workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, geospatial, mysql-8.0

I've got a column called 'coordinates' of type 'point'.

This query:

```
update `my-db`.`community` 
set `coordinates`= POINT( 31.9931217, 35.2823115 ) 
where 'id' = 1;
```

Returns the following error:

> cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

What is the proper formatting here?

Comment: do you have any null values in the coordinates field

Comment: do you have any index, it could be because of that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875327/spatial-index-in-mysql-error-cannot-get-geometry-object-from-data-you-send-t

Comment: id is indexed. Nothing beyond that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with: `'id'` is not a valid column name (that's a string litteral). As a general hint, you should avoid quoting the column names unless it is really necessary (ie when the name contains special characters or starts with a number, or clashes with a reserved word).

Apart from that, your syntax should work, as [described in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-mysql-specific-functions.html#function_point) and tested in [this DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/arnsRnaGFrJewHwS1iU8s1/0).

As an alernative, you can also [try and use `ST_GeomFromText()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/populating-spatial-columns.html), as follows:

```
update `my-db`.`community` 
SET `coordinates`= ST_GeomFromText('POINT(31.9931217 35.2823115)')
where `id` = 1;
```

Comment: Point(x, y) should also return a point object. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-mysql-specific-functions.html#function_point

Comment: @Shadow: you are correct, I tested it... I modified my answer accordingly. Thanks for the information... and for the update on my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the correct syntax is

> UPDATE `my-db`.`community` SET `coordinates`=GeomFromText('POINT(31.9931217 35.2823115)') WHERE 'id' = 1;

Try and see

Comment: Nope, point(x, y) should also return a point object. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-mysql-specific-functions.html#function_point